# ASP.NET Core: route parameter on a form submit action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, filtering, razor-pages, paging

I have an `Index` Razor page implemented with paging based on the tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-7.0#add-paging). I also implemented a user-selectable page sizing (details not shown here for brevity as it is not applicable to this problem) as well which I all have working. I am attempting to add the search functionality from the same page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-7.0#add-filtering). I have the search functionality working as well.

What I am struggling to get working is routing the current page size to the Get method when the search button is clicked.

Here is my search form from the index page:

```
<form asp-page="./Index" asp-route-pageSize="@Model.Logs.PageSize" method="get">
<div class="form-actions no-color">
    <p>
        Find by @nameof(Data.Audit.Log.Level):
        <select asp-for="@Model.LevelFilter" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel>()">
            <option selected="selected" value="@Model.LevelFilter">Please select</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-pageSize="@Model.Logs.PageSize" /> |
        <a asp-page="./Index" asp-route-pageSize="@Model.Logs.PageSize">Back to full List</a>
    </p>
</div>
</form>
```

And here is the `Get` method on the `Index` page:

```
public PaginatedList<Data.Audit.Log> Logs { get; set; }

public LogLevel? LevelFilter { get; set; }

public async Task OnGetAsync(int? pageIndex, int? pageSize, int? prevPageSize, LogLevel? levelFilter)
{
    LevelFilter = levelFilter;

    if (prevPageSize != null && pageSize != null && pageIndex != null && pageIndex > 1)
    {
        pageIndex = PaginatedList<Data.Audit.Log>.CalculateNewPageIndex(pageIndex.Value, prevPageSize.Value, pageSize.Value);
    }

    var query = DbContext.Logs.AsQueryable();

    if(levelFilter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.Level == levelFilter.ToString());
    }

    Logs = await PaginatedList<Data.Audit.Log>.CreateAsync(query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Logged).AsNoTracking(), pageIndex ?? 1, pageSize ?? _defaultPageSize);
}
```

As you can see in the `.cshtml` markup, I have tried putting the `asp-route-pageSize` on the form, input, and even the 'a' tag in the form. The html seems to be generated correctly:

[image]

The "Back for full List" behaves correctly and maintains the pageSize, however the Search button loses it. The only query parameter in this scenario added is the levelFilter. Any ideas what I am missing / doing wrong?

**UPDATE**: Here's the entire `.cshtml` for reference:

```
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<form asp-page="./Index" asp-route-pageSize="@Model.Logs.PageSize" method="get">
    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <p>
            Find by @nameof(Data.Audit.Log.Level):
            <select asp-for="@Model.LevelFilter" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel>()">
                <option selected="selected" value="@Model.LevelFilter">Please select</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-pageSize="@Model.Logs.PageSize" /> |
            <a asp-page="./Index" asp-route-pageSize="@Model.Logs.PageSize">Back to full List</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>

<table class="usa-table usa-table--striped usa-table--borderless">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Logs[0].Logged)
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Logs[0].Level)
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Logs[0].Message)
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Logs[0].UserName)
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Logs[0].Category)
            </th>
            <th>
                Action
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Logs)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Logged)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Level)
                </td>
                <td style="white-space:normal">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Message)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="usa-button usa-button--outline">Details</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<div id="pagingDiv" class="pages-div">
    @if (Model.Logs.HasPrevPage)
    {
        <a asp-page="./Index" asp-route-pageIndex="@(Model.Logs.PageIndex - 1)" asp-route-pageSize="@Model.Logs.PageSize" asp-route-levelFilter="@Model.LevelFilter" class="usa-button usa-button--outline">Prev</a>
    }

    @if (Model.Logs.ShowFirstPage)
    {
        <a asp-page="./Index" asp-route-pageIndex="@(1)" asp-route-pageSize="@Model.Logs.PageSize" asp-route-levelFilter="@Model.LevelFilter" class="usa-button usa-button--outline">1</a>
        <div class="inline-div">...</div>
    }

    @for (int i = Model.Logs.MinPage; i <= Model.Logs.MaxPage; i++)
    {
        if (Model.Logs.PageIndex == i)
        {
            <div class="non-button usa-button usa-button--active">@i.ToString()</div>
        }
        else
        {
            <a asp-page="./Index" asp-route-pageIndex="@i" asp-route-pageSize="@Model.Logs.PageSize" asp-route-levelFilter="@Model.LevelFilter" class="usa-button usa-button--outline">@i.ToString()</a>
        }
    }

    @if (Model.Logs.ShowLastPage)
    {
        <div class="inline-div">...</div>
        <a asp-page="./Index" asp-route-pageIndex="@Model.Logs.TotalPages" asp-route-pageSize="@Model.Logs.PageSize" asp-route-levelFilter="@Model.LevelFilter" class="usa-button usa-button--outline">@Model.Logs.TotalPages</a>
    }

    @if (Model.Logs.HasNextPage)
    {
        <a asp-page="./Index" asp-route-pageIndex="@(Model.Logs.PageIndex + 1)" asp-route-pageSize="@Model.Logs.PageSize" asp-route-levelFilter="@Model.LevelFilter" class="usa-button usa-button--outline">Next</a>
    }
</div>
<div id="pagingDiv" class="records-per-page-div">
    @foreach(var i in Model.Logs.PageSizes)
    {
        if (Model.Logs.PageSize == i)
        {
            <div class="non-button usa-button usa-button--active">@i.ToString()</div>
        }
        else
        {
            <a asp-page="./Index" asp-route-pageIndex="@Model.Logs.PageIndex" asp-route-pageSize="@i" asp-route-prevPageSize="@Model.Logs.PageSize"
                asp-route-levelFilter="@Model.LevelFilter" class="usa-button usa-button--outline">@i.ToString()</a>
        }
    }
</div>
```

Comment: The form will take all the values inside the form and generate the GET.  Since you don't have a "results per page" option in your form, you actually don't need to pass that value around.  Just hard-code it in the backend to whatever you like.  If you wanted the user to be able to choose that, create a select control with various values and use asp-for.  (if you really want to keep passing around the same value, you should use a hidden field with asp-for)

Comment: Thanks @pcalkins: I realize I can hard code constants, but the pageSize is user selectable.

Comment: ok, so you just need to add the <select> tag for the option...  that will pass the value.  Don't put the asp-route-pageSize= bit in there.  (right now it's in your <form> tag)

Comment: Thanks @pcalkins.  I added the entire cshtml in the post. The selecting of the pagesize shouldn't be an issue as it is already selected and flows properly in all of the other page calls with the asp-route-pageSize. In this form section of the page (because it's a search box), I want to flow the already selected pageSize. As you can see in the generated html the value is already there.

Comment: since that's not in the form, it won't be included when the form submits.  You can either add a select in the form, or just add the field as a hidden field.   ex: <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Logs.PageSize">

Comment: Thanks @pcalkins! I had tried that before and it was yielding this string for the query string: "/Audit/Log?Logs.PageSize=25&LevelFilter=4".  You helping to assure me that it was the right track helped me find that I needed to add a name="pageSize" to the hidden input tag:

<input asp-for="@Model.Logs.PageSize" name="pageSize" type="hidden" />

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

With much help from [@pcalkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4744568/pcalkins), here is the correct answer. I had to add the hidden input tag mapped to the Model.Logs.PagSize as well as give it the name of the parameter I wanted on the query string:

```
<input asp-for="@Model.Logs.PageSize" name="pageSize" type="hidden" />
```

Here's the full form:

```
<form asp-page="./Index" method="get">
    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <input asp-for="@Model.Logs.PageSize" name="pageSize" type="hidden" />
        <p>
            Find by @nameof(Data.Audit.Log.Level):
            <select asp-for="@Model.LevelFilter" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel>()">
                <option selected="selected" value="@Model.LevelFilter">Please select</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" /> |
            <a asp-page="./Index" asp-route-pageSize="@Model.Logs.PageSize">Back to full List</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```